# switch between current and previous workspace in awesome-wm

Tags: awesome-wm

In dwm you can switch between the current and previous workspace with alt-tab. Is there any way to do the same thing in awesome, or perhaps configure it to do so?

Answer (score 9):

According to [source, 3.4.11](http://git.naquadah.org/?p=awesome.git;a=blob;f=awesomerc.lua.in;h=c48aa139aa1201aba0cdb0ef272c2dcbc23b6c78;hb=3d4d1955dac08e2dda0b756da72ec9a98b75b230#l198) you should press
<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: I've long switched to i3 since.

Comment: Was this the correct answer @fergusdawson?

Comment: This answered my question, which was the same as @fergusdawson's.